# how to union those query ?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, union

i want to union two query in one select, problem that
if i use "union" all say that  different number of columns

first select -

```
select users.fromsite,count(*) from users where users.fromsite != '' and users.fromsite is not null group by users.fromsite;
```

second select -

```
select sum(transfers.mimgebis_before), sum(transfers.mimgebis_after), users.fromsite,count(*) from transfers  join users on transfers.player_id = users.pid where transfers.player_id in (select  users.pid  from users where users.fromsite in (select  users.fromsite from users where fromsite != '' )) and users.fromsite != '' and transfers.date_created between '2013-12-10 08:20:00' and '2015-12-10 08:30:06'  group by users.fromsite limit 0,5;
```

first query results are here:

```
|| *fromsite* || *count(*)* ||
|| fortunejack.de || 2 ||
|| google.com || 3 ||
|| youtube.com || 2 ||
```

second query results are here:

```
|| *sum(transfers.mimgebis_before)* || *sum(transfers.mimgebis_after)* || *fromsite* || *count(*)* ||
|| 20000.000000000 ||  || fortunejack.de || 1 ||
|| 53335.000000000 || 2000.000000000 || google.com || 2 ||
```

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Edit your question and show what you want the final results to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want a `union` -- that would require that the columns be the same for the two queries.  I think you just want a `left join`, where you append the columns from the second query onto the first.  Something like this:

```
select fs.fromsite, fs.cnt1, t.val1, t.val2, t.cnt2
from (select u.fromsite, count(*) as cnt1
      from users u
      where u.fromsite <> '' and u.fromsite is not null
      group by u.fromsite
     ) fs left join
     (select sum(t.mimgebis_before) as val1, sum(t.mimgebis_after) as val2, u.fromsite, count(*) as cnt2
      from transfers t join
          users u
          on t.player_id = u.pid
      where t.player_id in (select users.pid  from users where users.fromsite in (select  users.fromsite from users where fromsite != '' )) and
           u.fromsite <> '' and t.date_created between '2013-12-10 08:20:00' and '2015-12-10 08:30:06'     
      group by u.fromsite limit 0,5
     ) t
     on t.fromsite = fs.fromsite;
```